# What is the correct syntax for the SOURCE command in SQL

Tags: mysql, codeanywhere

In codeAnywhere I'm trying to run pre written script files to create a table. When using codeAnywhere one must import the file to the shell for the code first, as I have done. However I have been unable to use the `SOURCE` command to run these files. I have currently attempted this syntax:

```
USE exams SOURCE students.txt;
```

What is the correct syntax here? Do I need to name the database in the syntax?
Are there other commands which run text files containing code?

***EDIT:*** I tried using this syntax, to the following result:

> ERROR: Failed to open file 'exams(question5.txt)', error: 2

Comment: MySQL does not have any commands / statements named `source`, therefore there is no way you could make it work there. You need to import the textual data into a table in MySQL to be able to use it from there. I do not really understand what you are trying to achive with this question.

Comment: @Shadow I am trying to run a a script contain the code necessary to create a table.

Comment: is using \. an option?

Comment: @Shadow "MySQL does not have any commands / statements named source..."  This is from the docs: "If you are already running mysql, you can execute an SQL script file using the source command or \. command:
mysql> source file_name". It's been around since at least 5.6 (2013)

Comment: @jbobbins like the OP you are mixing up mysql server with mysql command line tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the shell you can use the following command to execute the queries from a text file:

```
mysql db_name < text_file
```

**Hint:** If the `USE` command (with correct database name) is specified on the textfile you don't need to specify the database. The `SOURCE` command is not available on MySQL instead you need the `<`.

> You can find more information about executing queries from text files here:
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Answer (score 4):

Put the commands on separate lines, without semi-colons for the shell commands, and if this doesn't work, then prefix with `\` as well (I don't need to on my setup, but it's in the docs):

```
USE exams

SOURCE students.txt
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-shell-commands.html